# How to put variable into find

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have products, productinfos and infos with categories

In my Info model I have a

```
named_scope :general
```

Which gets all records that belong to the category with the name general.

Then in my view I have a loop going through all categories
lets say I then have

```
asset = 'general'
```

now I would like to do

```
@generalinfos = @product.infos."#{asset}"
```

But this doesn't work.
Any ideas, how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@product.infos.send(asset)
```